# How to connect to Azure AD tenant which does not have a subscription from PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD tenant which is not associated to a subscription. When I login from the Azure portal I am able see and get to it using "switch directories".

When I log in from PowerShell, I do not see it, it only shows my subscription not by Azure AD tenant.

How do I connect to the Azure AD tenant which has no subscription?

Comment: whats the point, you wouldn't be able to do anything. unless you are talking about `Connect-AzureAD`, that should work

Comment: I would like to create an application from powershell in that directory

Answer (score 4):

Neither the Azure AD PowerShell nor the Azure PowerShell modules require that the tenant have an Azure subscription in order to connect.

If you are using the [Azure AD PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0) module, you simply connect:

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

If you are using a user account which is a member of multiple tenants, it's best to be explicit about which tenant you'd like to connect to:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId "{other-tenant-id}"
```

For registering and managing apps in Azure AD I recommend using the Azure AD PowerShell module. However, if you need/want to use the [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/overview) module instead, the process is very similar:

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

And, if you need to be explicit:

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId "{other-tenant-id}"
```