# how I can make an service principal as an App Registration Owner with azure portal or PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions

so the background as follows:

for installation and deployment process we need  to  modify a customer created App Registration.
but we get not the right `Application.ReadWriteAll` but we could get `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`.

I know that if creating  an Graph Api Call (excecuted with Postman) as shown below it worked, because Creator is automatically the Owner.
.

```
 HTTP-Post Request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications   
with body:
     {
      "displayName": "AppRegName"
    }
```

But I need to solution with standard tool like azure portal or powershell and I found no way to assign or remove a service principal as owner to an App Registration.

Is there a way to to do this with powershell?

The authentifiaction with an service principal i dont't know how I can do it?

I think after I can  create an App Registration with
 `$appRegistration = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "AppRegCreatebyPS"`
but I very unexperinced in using powershell.
So how I can tell powershell to use the service principal authentitification for creating App Registrations?

A short extra question:

Can I remove later the owner role for the service principal and how can I do it?

Thanks for all Readers And I hope someone can give me a hint.

Comment: Hello , if I am correct you want to set a Service Principal as a owner to App registration?

Comment: **yes** and with graph api calls it worked over postman.
it is only for installation purposes not permanent.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT : or you know another variant if you must do changes in 1 or 2 customers  App Registrations but you get not application.ReadWrite.All. readWrite by Owned  is a possible way to solve it. We have no user access for the App registration for installation we can get Serv. Pr. access. to 2 App registrations. If there are other proposals please post it as  comment if it is not an direct answer to the question.

Comment: Hello @AnsumanBal-MT , First many Thanks iI try as soon as possible, but it could be tommorow I think and then I give you feedback.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT : I wait  today for support of a colleague, I have no permission assign remove roles. So it is delay 1 day and I hope I can test it today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create App registration, Service Principal for App registration, Add application owner and remove application owner all from PowerShell AzureAD module.

**Command to install Azure AD module in PowerShell:**

```
Install-Module AzureAD
```

**You can use the below commands :**

```
#Connect to Azure AD 
Connect-AzureAD

#Create Azure AD app Registration
$appRegistration = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName "AppRegCreatebyPS"

# Create A service Principal for the above app Registration
New-AzureADServicePrincipal -AccountEnabled $true -AppId $appRegistration.AppId -AppRoleAssignmentRequired $true -DisplayName $appRegistration.DisplayName

# get objectid for the service principal
$serviceprincipal= Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'AppRegCreatebyPS'"

#Get the old app registration for whom you want set owner
$oldappregistration = Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Postman'"

#add service principal to the application owner of old app registration
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $oldappregistration.ObjectId -RefObjectId $serviceprincipal.ObjectId

# verify the owner for the old app registration
Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $oldappregistration.ObjectId

#remove the owner for the old app registration
Remove-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $oldappregistration.ObjectId -OwnerId $serviceprincipal.ObjectId
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Cmdlts for Azure AD module reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#applications)

Comment: it works generally fine, there some problems in our special constellation , we have 2 tenants with 1high restricted subscription in 1 tenant.  So `  Set-AzContext -TenantId xxxxx-...` or `Connect-AzureAD -TenantId xxxxx-...` to ensure in the correct tenant works reliable in every case but this another topic. Your answer was very good ad easy to understand. Thanks.

Comment: my different tenant problem seems to be handled here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57005048/how-to-connect-to-azure-ad-tenant-which-does-not-have-a-subscription-from-powers

or here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/778561/azure-powershell-change-directory

Comment: I found this as an alternative way (connect as Service Pr. and create  an App Registration and get an implcit owner role): see example 3 in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0  
I have not tested it, but it seems another good easy way.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done like below from bash or windows subsystem linux.

Login to your Azure account

az login

Execute below command

az ad app owner add --id AAAA --owner-object-id  AAAA

--id(Application id) , --owner-object-id (Owners object id)

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/owner?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I'm getting the same results as in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201329/how-to-add-another-service-principal-as-an-owner-to-app-registration