# How to add another Service principal as an owner to App Registration

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-service-principal

I have two Apps Registered in Azure (Let's say App_One and App_Two) I want to add App_Two as an owner to App_One.

I tried to add using below AZ CLI command.

```
az ad app owner add --id <CLIENT_ID_OF_APP_ONE>  --owner-object-id <OBJECT_ID_OF_APP_TWO>
```

But it gives below error

```
The reference target 'Application_OBJECT_ID_OF_APP_TWO' of type 'Application' is invalid for the 'owners' reference
```

Comment: Is this a new thing? Because few months ago I was able to add the same App as an owner without any issue

Answer (score 1):

When I ran that CLI command in my environment, I got **same error** as you like below:

```
az ad app owner add --id <CLIENT_ID_OF_APP_ONE>  --owner-object-id <OBJECT_ID_OF_APP_TWO>
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, you can add service principal as **owner of group** not as
> owner of application via Azure CLI.

When I ran below command, service principal added as **owner of the group** successfully like below:

```
az ad group owner add --group DemoGroup --owner-object-id <OBJECT_ID_OF_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below **PowerShell command** to add service principal as owner of application.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Add-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $AppObjectId -RefObjectId  $SPObjectId
Get-AzureADApplicationOwner -ObjectId $AppObjectId
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[possibility of adding service principal owners with the cli - GitHub by **Mykp3**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/9250#issuecomment-1315273334)

Comment: Connect-AzureAD                   
Connect-AzureAD: The term 'Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. I'm getting this error

Comment: Check if **AzureAD** module is installed or not. Use these commands to install and import it: `Install-Module AzureAD` and `Import-Module AzureAD` before running `Connect-AzureAD` command.